# how to dynamically exit a jquery $.each()?

Tags: jquery, loops, each

i have a list of images which i am getting through ajax and then using jquery $.each() i loop through the images and display a image one after the other after an interval of one second. 
I want the user to be able click on a stop button and so that the user can stop at a particular image if he wants to.
So i need to dynamically exit $.each() when the user clicks on the stop button.
Is it possible to do it?

Comment: How about a code sample?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You can use `return false` to break out of `each()` loops early.

#### Example:

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
      $("div").each(function (index, domEle) {
        // domEle == this
        $(domEle).css("backgroundColor", "yellow"); 
        if ($(this).is("#stop")) {
          $("span").text("Stopped at div index #" + index);
          return false;
        }
      });
    });

</script>
```

**Source**: http://api.jquery.com/each/

Comment: once a get the data through a ajax call i pass the data to a function 
show_images(data){

if($('#stop').is(':visible')){ return false; }else{ //diplay next image }

}


$(".stop").click(function(){
 $("#stop").hide();  
});

this does not work

Comment: But you must return `false`.  You cannot early return with `true`.

Answer (score 13):

To break out of an `each()` loop you would:

```
return false;
```

So your button could set a variable when clicked that the each loop checks each pass, then returns false when the variable is set.

http://api.jquery.com/each/

Answer (score 4):

http://api.jquery.com/each/

> We can stop the loop from within the
>   callback function by returning false.

Answer (score 3):

```
return(false);
```

should do it.

Answer (score -1):

Use `return false;` between each loop.