# How to escape from for ... each loop and method at the same time?

Tags: jquery, foreach, escaping, exit

I am using the code below, that iterating over select options. I checked if options value has already entered. It escapes from for-each but it doesn't exit from method.

```
yeniIlacBagla_ilacBagla: function(){
    $("#bagliIlaclar > option").each(function(){
        if(this.value===$("#baglanacakIlacID").val()){
            alert($("#baglanacakIlacAdi").val()+'\n adlı ilaç zaten bağlıdır!'); 
            return;
        }else{
            $("#bagliIlaclar").append($('<option></option>').val($("#baglanacakIlacID").val()).html($("#baglanacakIlacAdi").val()));
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You need to return false.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973333/how-to-dynamically-exit-a-jquery-each

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation of jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) I found the following

> We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the
>   callback function **return false**. Returning non-false is the same as a
>   continue statement in a for loop; it will skip immediately to the next
>   iteration.

Comment: Technically, @caglaror is using `.each()` and not `jQuery.each`, though the answers for both happen to be the same.

Comment: Thank you , but i can exit for-each with any `return` or `return false`, but it continue to iterate. How to check if its not carried on?

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/each/ :

> You can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning `false.`