# How to exit (escape) a function from for loop inside of it?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach

This is theoretical question to understand how many escapes (return or exit) can apply to nested loops or other controls and functions.

I confused about this because I am stuck in the code 
[How to escape from for ... each loop and method at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574121/how-to-escape-from-for-each-loop-and-method-at-the-same-time)

I can't stop iterating over `option`s in `select` element.

I tried `return` and `return false` already, but am unsuccesful.

Generally how we can do that?

```
function() {
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            $(...).each(function() {
               // You have to exit outer function from here
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? php?

Comment: judging by the link in his post, I'd say jquery

Comment: Sorry @Evan javascript.

Comment: i think you can use return false

Comment: @PSR i used `return false`, @nalply yes i used `each()`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested jQuery.each() - continue/break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3267508/nested-jquery-each-continue-break)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a shared variable between the loops. Flip it to `true` at the end of the `each()` loop if you want to exit and at the end of the `for-loop` check for it being `true`. If yes, break out of it.

Comment: Yes @Konstantin D this will solve my problem. But shall we say there is no direct solution to this?

Comment: @caglaror I would say yes.

Answer (score 4):

**I would do it this way:**

- Create a boolean variable to check on each loop, and if the variable is true, then exit the loop (do this for each).

  ```
  var exitLoop = false;

   $(sentences).each(function() {
      if(exitLoop) {return;}
      var s = this;
      alert(s);
      $(words).each(function(i) {
      if(exitLoop) {return;}
          if (s.indexOf(this) > -1)
          {
              alert('found ' + this);
              throw "Exit Error";
          }
      });
  });
  ```

**Note** this is *not* the correct use of a `try-catch` as a `try-catch` should strictly be used for error handling, not jumping to different sections of your code - but it will work for what you're doing.

If `return` is not doing it for you, try using a `try-catch`

```
try{
$(sentences).each(function() {
    var s = this;
    alert(s);
    $(words).each(function(i) {
        if (s.indexOf(this) > -1)
        {
            alert('found ' + this);
            throw "Exit Error";
        }
    });
});
}
catch (e)
{
    alert(e)
}
```

Code taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3267593/220060)

Comment: This code works fine, there is no reason for a downvote. Care to explain?

Comment: A try catch should be used for error handling, not for jumping to different sections of a script.

Comment: @nalply I edited, not sure what you're looking for to be honest

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26869/discussion-between-nalply-and-evan)

Answer (score 1):

The loop can also be exited by changing the iterator value.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

for(var i = 0;i<arr.length;i++){

  console.log(i);
  compute(i);

  function compute(num){
    //break is illegal here
    //return ends only compute function
    if(num>=3) i=arr.length;
  }

}
```

Comment: But the nested loops? Inner loops will continue to iterate.

Answer (score 0):

"label"s are the solution for scope processes like breaking loops. Here is the built-in answer I realized after years: https://css-tricks.com/you-can-label-a-javascript-if-statement/

Answer (score 0):

Not ideal but you can do

```
let result = false;
function() {
    for (...) {
        if (...) {
            $(...).each(function() {
                result = true;
               
            });
        }
    }
    if (result == true){
        return;
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As in most languages. The keyword to exit a loop is `break;`
More info here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_break.asp

Comment: Just wondering to the down voter? What is incorrect about my answer?

Comment: if the point of i wrote comment we `break;` the code it said break is Illegal at there.

Comment: I don't know if you realize, but `for each()` is not javascript code. At least not that I know of

Comment: I've said this before. Not everything on wc3schools.com is wrong. And if the link I posted contains correct information, please shut it.